# Setting environment variable in shell script does not make it visible to the shell

Tags: unix, export, environment-variables

I want to use a shell script that I can call to set some environment variables. However, after the execution of the script, I don't see the environment variable using "printenv" in bash.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello!"
export MYVAR=boubou
echo "After setting MYVAR!"
```

When I do "./test.sh", I see:

```
Hello!
After setting MYVAR!
```

When I do "printenv MYVAR", I see nothing.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is how environment variables work. Every process has a copy of the environment. Any changes that the process makes to its copy propagate to the process's children. They do not, however, propagate to the process's parent.

One way to get around this is by using the `source` command:

```
source ./test.sh
```

or

```
. ./test.sh
```

(the two forms are synonymous).

When you do this, instead of running the script in a sub-shell, `bash` will execute each command in the script as if it were typed at the prompt.

Comment: It works, but why "bash test.sh" does not set the environment variable? If bash executes each command in the script as if it is typed in the prompt, the environment variable would be set in the current process?

Comment: @GDICommander: No. When you run `bash test.sh`, this creates a new `bash` process that executes the script **and exits**.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Now, I understand environment variables a little bit better.

Comment: How to run it with `sudo` ? I get `sudo: .: command not found`

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative would be to have the script *print* the variables you want to set, with `echo export VAR=value` and do `eval "$(./test.sh)"` in your main shell. This is the approach used by various programs [e.g. resize, dircolors] that provide environment variables to set.

This only works if the script has no other output (or if any other output appears on stderr, with `>&2`)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a common pattern and has several advantages.