# Create linux environment variable using vagrant provisioner

Tags: vagrant

I've got vagrant running Ubuntu for development purposes.  I've used a shell script provisioner to download/install my dependencies and create some aliases, but I've hit a wall in terms of using the provisioner to create environment variables (which are used for several flags within my project).  Originally I had something like:

```
export MY_VAR='value'
```

Into my provisioner script, but then found out that you can't [add environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604462/setting-environment-variable-in-shell-script-does-not-make-it-visible-to-the-she) from inside a shell script by running it normally.  Fair enough, so I tried instead changing my line of the Vagrantfile to:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: “source setup.sh"
```

Which didn't solve the problem.  Environment variables still weren't there.  I tried adding the exports directly as an inline:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: “export MY_VAR='value'"
```

No luck.  Still no global environment when I ssh'ed in.  Is there a way to use the shell script to set a bash environment variable, or is it time to throw in the towel on shell provisioners and learn chef?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should have the provisioning script add a line to your .profile:

```
echo "export VAR=value" >> ~/.profile
```

On login, the .profile script will be read by bash and the variable will be set.

Comment: A note for others, I'm using CentOS 7 and I had to do 
`echo "export VAR=value" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: This fix does not follow the "vagrant way". Adding this as is in vagrant will append a new line on every provision cicle

Comment: @Maks3w: Fair critique, though easily fixed (added an answer showing how)

Comment: perhaps this answer could be modified to be complete, eg, show the entire config.vm.... line?

Answer (score 20):

Seeing as the accepted answer does indeed add an `export VAR=value` to your .profile (or .bashrc) file each time you run `vagrant provision`, here's how I've added environment variables quickly

```
source ~/.profile && [ -z "$VAR" ] && echo "export VAR=value" >> ~/.profile
```

Breakdown:

- `source ~/.profile`: load the current `.profile` file
- `[ -z "$VAR"]`: check whether or not `VAR` is set, if not:
- `echo "export VAR=value" >> ~/.profile`: add the export line to `.profile`

Putting it all together:

I normally use puphpet for my vagrant boxes, so I tend to stick to the directory structure it uses, which means putting my provisioning script in `puphpet/shell/*` (relative to the `Vagrantfile` file). In that file, you can add as many environment variables as you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Replace .profile with .bashrc if required
source ~/.profile
if [ -z "$VAR" ]; then # only checks if VAR is set, regardless of its value
    echo "export VAR=value" >> ~/.profile
fi
#other env variables and profile stuff here
```

If you want to set the environment variables to a specific value, even if they're set, you can replace `[ -z "$VAR" ]` with this (As Maks3w suggested):

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ] || [ "$VAR" != "value" ]; then
    #same as before
fi
```

Then simply add this to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "puphpet/shell/your-script.sh"
```

That ought to do the trick...

Comment: I like the use of -z switch instead grep

Comment: I have answer with a 100% full Vagrant wat (without external script file)

Comment: @Maks3w: That would be a valid option, too. Not sure about the `[ $VAR != "value" ]` bit, since the env variable might could've been changed by the user of the vbox for development reasons, and he might not want the values to change by provisioning

Comment: The provision phase of Vagrant since 1.4 (IIRC) is under user demand. So if he/she launch the provision phase then really wants reset the configs.

Comment: @Maks3w: Not necessarily. I use vagrant at work, we work in teams, and it often happens that someone updates the vagrant repo (add a vhost, or set up a new tool), which requires us to provision the boxes. I'd like the provisioning to _add_ the new stuff, without it disrupting my own changes. It's all down to the specific requirements/use-case of the OP IMHO

Comment: We could chat about this but that approach IMO break the wonderful vagrant destroy && vagrant up for to have clean workspaces.

Comment: Works better than the approved answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I got `$GOPATH` working:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  echo -n                              >  /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
  echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go'        >> /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
  echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin' >> /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
SHELL
```

The use of single quotes and `$HOME` (instead of `~`) were necessary---I couldn't make it work otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

This answer shows how to add environment variables just modifying `VagrantFile` using Ruby HEREDOC (Here doc) syntax

```
  $install_user_vars = <<SCRIPT
    source ~/.profile

    if [ -z "$VAR" ] || [ "$VAR" != "value" ]; then
      echo "export VAR=value" >> ~/.profile
    fi

    if [ $(pwd) != "/vagrant" ]; then
      echo "cd /vagrant" >> ~/.profile
    fi

SCRIPT

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $install_user_vars
```

Note: The close `SCRIPT` must be the first character in his own line

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing. I wanted to set `http(s)_proxy` environment variables in Vagrantfile. The requirement was that I can change these variables at any time and `vagrant reload` to apply them.

Finally, I came up with the solution:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "> /etc/profile.d/myvars.sh", run: "always"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"export http_proxy=http://proxy.somedomain.com:3128\" >> /etc/profile.d/myvars.sh", run: "always"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"export https_proxy=https://proxy.somedomain.com:3128\" >> /etc/profile.d/myvars.sh", run: "always"
```

0) /etc/profile.d/*.sh scripts are run at the startup of the bash shell
1) removes everything from myvars.sh
2) sets the first variable
3) sets the second variable

Because of [run: "always"](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.html#run-once-or-always) I can add/remove variables and after `vagrant reload` they are applied.

Answer (score 0):

In CentOs7 you need to place env vars under `/etc/profile.d/` 
This worked in my case:

```
machine.vm.provision 'shell',
  inline: 'sudo su - && echo "export VAR1=test export VAR2=test" > /etc/profile.d/vars.sh'
```