# vagrant and chef: how set Ubuntu environment variable?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

Using Chef 11.4, I am trying to get `vagrant up` to set an environment variable. Specifically, the TZ env variable that sets the VM's timezone.

It works fine manually, if I `vagrant ssh` then type `export TZ=America/Los_Angeles` then type `date` I see the time in West Coast time zone (as opposed to ubuntu's default UTC).

But I cannot figure out how to effective run `export TZ=America/Los_Angeles` within Vagrantfile so it executes when I run `vagrant up`

I've tried it 3 different ways, including attempting to write it to the .profile file. None of them work. (Th e.profile file does not get edited, and the TZ variable does not get set.

```
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: %q{export TZ=America/Los_Angeles}
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: %q{sudo bash -c "export TZ=America/Phoenix" >> ~/.profile}
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: %q{echo "export TZ=America/New_york" >> ~/.profile}
```

the output after running `vagrant up` is:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
```

But the environment variable does not get set directly, nor does the .profile fiel get edited

Comment: Are you sure? Chef is run as root, so you are changing /root/.profile. There is also a similar question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707986/create-linux-environment-variable-using-vagrant-provisioner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is twofold... the file should be in the `.bashrc` file (at least for the Linux I'm using), and instead of `~` must use the full path which is `/home/vagrant/.bashrc`.

Comment: Just note this will set the timezone only for the **vagrant** user (not system wide, any other daemon/user will get the default timezone). If you really wish to set it system wide you should modify `/etc/timezone` under ubuntu and the `ZONE` variable in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` for RHEL5 (can't say for other distro)

Comment: Excellent point. In our case we're setting it for ruby apps and workers, which  use TZ env variable. So the approach I found above works for that case, but probably only for that case.