# How to add to slave's PATH using Slave SetupPlugin?

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 RHEL machines setup in a Master/Slave configuration using Jenkins ver. 1.609.2

The slave is being launched via SSH Slaves Plugin 1.10.

I'm trying to use the [Slave Setup Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slave+Setup+Plugin) v 1.9 to install the tools that will be necessary for my slave machine to run builds. In particular I am installing sqlplus.

Here is the script that I am running in order to try installing sqlplus:

```bash
if command -v sqlplus >/dev/null; then
    echo "sqlplus already setup. Nothing to do."
else
    #Create directory for sqlplus and unzip it there.
    mkdir /jenkins/tools/sqlplus
    tar -xvf sqlplussetup/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.tar.gz -C /jenkins/tools/sqlplus  || { echo 'unzip failed' ; exit 1; }
    tar -xvf sqlplussetup/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.tar.gz -C /jenkins/tools/sqlplus  || { echo 'unzip failed' ; exit 1; }

    cd /jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1

    #Create links for the Oracle libs
    ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so || { echo 'Could not create link' ; exit 1; }
    ln -s libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so || { echo 'Could not create link' ; exit 1; }

    #Add two lines to .bashrc only if they don't already exist. Export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and add sqlplus to PATH.
    grep -q -F 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' /home/jenkins/.bashrc || echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> /home/jenkins/.bashrc
    grep -q -F 'export PATH=$PATH:/jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1' /home/jenkins/.bashrc || echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1' >> /home/jenkins/.bashrc

    #Export variables so they can be used right away
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export PATH=$PATH:/jenkins/tools/sqlplus/instantclient_12_1

    echo "sqlplus has been setup."
fi
```

This script runs successfully and everything appears to work until I try to run a build and execute the `sqlplus` command. The build fails because `sqlplus` is not a recognized command.

My main question is this:
*What is the proper way to automatically add an environment variable when launching a slave?*

Please note I am looking for an **automated** way of doing this. I don't want to go into the configuration screen for my slave, tick a checkbox and specify an environment variable. That is counter-productive to what I am trying to achieve which is a slave that is immediately usable for builds once connected.

---

I pretty much understand why my script doesn't work. When Jenkins is launching the slave it first makes an SSH connection and then it runs my setup script using the command

```
/bin/sh -xe /jenkins/tmp/hudson8035138410767957141.sh
```

Where the contents of `hudson8035138410767957141.sh` is my script from above. So obviously, the `export` [isn't going to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8604485/953327). I was hoping adding the exports to the `.bashrc` file would get around this but it does not work. I *think* this is because this script is executed after the ssh connection is established and therefore the `.bashrc` has already been read.

Problem is I can't figure out any way to work around this limitation.

Comment: We use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin for setting up variables before running actual jobs.  If you follow some conventions about installations, this could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash does not read any of its startup files (`.bashrc`, `.profile` etc) for non-interative shells that don't have the `--login` option set explicitly -- that's why the exports don't work.

So, solution "A" is to keep the bashrc magic that you suggest above, and to add the `--login` option by changing the first line in your build step to

```
#!/bin/bash --login

<your script here>
```

The explicit shebang at on the first line will also prevent excessive debug output that you get from the default's `-x` option (see your console snippet above).

Alternative solution "B" uses the fact that bash will source any script whose name is given in `$BASH_ENV` (if that variable is defined and the file exists). Define that variable globally in your slave properties (e.g., set to /jenkins/tools/setup.sh) and add exports as needed during slave setup. Every bash shell build step will read the settings then.

With solution "B" you don't need to use the `--login` option and you don't have to mess up the `.bashrc`. However, the "BASH_ENV" feature is only active when bash runs in "bash mode". As Jenkins starts the shell via `sh`, bash tries to emulate historic sh, which does not have that feature. So, also for B, you need a shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash

<your script here>
```

But that you'd need anyway to get rid of the tracing output that's usually too much in production setups.

Comment: I like your solution "B". If I understand correctly, if I were to `export` `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside the `$BASH_ENV` script, those would remain throughout the build step? Unfortunately, I am no longer working on the project that required this so I can't actually test it out.

Comment: Yes. Commands/exports in `$BASH_ENV` are read during bash startup and persist for the whole shell session -- exactly the same as for statements that you'd add to `.bashrc` etc for interactive login shells.